# How can I customize what RPi displays on boot?

Tags: boot, display, raspberry-pi-os

I'm new to the RPi world, but

I'm using RPi 4 with official Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS (bullseye) right now.

When the RPi start booting, it normally displays rainbow screen, then some splash screen, before it enters desktop.

So, what if I want to customize that?

Let's say, I would like to show my custom splash screen through out the booting process, without rainbow screen, until it enter desktop.

Is that possible? Would you please suggest a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a duplicate question ([Remove boot messages (all text) in Jessie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59310/remove-boot-messages-all-text-in-jessie) AND [Custom Splash Screen Video](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48084/custom-splash-screen-video)). Though you kind of combined two questions into one. I'll help you get started.

You can disable splash screen (rainbow), the RPi logo's (the Raspberry Icons while booting) and disable dmesg logs (kernel logs) while booting. It is also possible to disable the flashing cursor while booting.

1. Disable rainbow:
   Set `disable_splash=1` in `/boot/config.txt`
2. Disable Pi logo's:
   Add `logo.nologo` to the `/boot/cmdline.txt` file
3. Mute kernel logs (only show critical errors):
   Add `loglevel=3` to the `/boot/cmdline.txt` file
4. Remove blinking cursor:
   Add `vt.global_cursor_default=0` to the `/boot/cmdline.txt` file

This should leave you with only a black screen until the desktop environment is done booting.

You 'could' add a custom splash screen. Although in my experience, this add extra time to the boot process, since the system will have to wait until enough drivers are loaded to display graphics. In my experience it is usually a waste of start-up time. This post explains how to add a static image, or even a video in the startup sequence: https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/custom-raspberry-pi-splash-screen

Good luck.

Comment: Can you provide the example for cmdline.txt? Where should I add it? I tried adding those in the end of cmdline.txt and my Pi won't load anymore (only black screen)

Comment: I tried resetting my my SD card and rewrite backup img to it and now it works fine after those line in the end. So perhaps its my doing something between that broke it.

Comment: I believe that the cmdline.txt may never have more than 1 line in the file. The file also states where the system can find your boot partition. Changing that parameter might screw over your boot.

Comment: States where the system van find your *root* partition*